# How to add crop functionality in camera taker app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, crop

I have implemented picking image from gallery or take photo and i am displaying in in uiimage view in screen. But i want to implement crop functionality.

Measn that, after i take photo from phone then i need to crop and then i need to display in my screen. How to do that ??

Here my code :

```
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBOutlet weak var imagevView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func ChooseImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera


    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    imagevView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is something helpful [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=swift+crop+photo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vfSJWOeRA6Ss8wep3Y7wBg).

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/justwudi/WDImagePicker may be its helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can, to some extend, use the `imagePicker.allowsEditing = true` setting. If you want more advanced cropping something like what @Kamlesh suggest might be what you are looking for.